# How to assign Shortcut (Alt+<key>) to SWT button with image?

Tags: button, swt, shortcut, alt

I'm developing a RCP application, where I need to assign shortcut (**Alt+[key]**) to **SWT Button with image**.
I'm able to assign shortcut to Button with text using "&" character, 
fox ex: button.setText("&Select All"); then Alt+S will act as shortcut fot that button.

I have 2 questions regarding this:

1. How to assign Alt+[key] shortcut to SWT button with images (no text), without using key listener?
2. How to assign Alt+[key] shortcut to SWT button with text, but no shortcut key letter in that text, again without using key listener.
   for ex: "UnFix" is the text on button and shortcut key should be Alt+Q.

I hope there should be a way to do this in SWT.

Comment: You say an RCP but then ask about SWT. Eclipse plugins have code for this, but it is not in SWT. So is this just SWT or an Eclipse RCP with plugins?

Comment: Greg, its Eclipse RCP application with plugins, but I have used SWT components to design my user interface.

Comment: For plugins you would normally use a command, handler and key binding to set up shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

You can select a mnemonic by placing an ampersand before the letter that should serve as the mnemonic letter (like `"&Select All"`).

If the control does not have a text or the desired letter does not occur in that text, you will ned to use key event listener. There is no way around that.

Some applications work around the 'missing letter' in that they place the mnemonic letter in brackes like this: `"UnFix (&Q)"`. Though this technically work, I find this an esthetically rather unfortunate choice.

Using an *unobvious* mnemonic letter has also usability issues: how would a user ever know or memorize that <kbd>Alt+Q</kbd> means 'UnFix'?

Comment: I agree with you about usability issue the user may face due to unobivious mnemonic, thats why I have given tooltips to buttons for showing shortcut also. I just wanted to confirm the other way of assigning shortcuts to buttons with images, and your answer resolved it, Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I have assigned shortcut to Buttons using "&" while setting text, but I'm not able to call action written for that button on pressing shortcut. If I need to use keyEvent listener for this purpose also, then what is the use of using "&"?

Comment: It might be that mnemonics aren't supported on all platforms. What OS or window system are you using?

Comment: I'm using windows 7, 32 bit OS. Right now I have added selectionListner on button to call specific action. Now pressing Alt+<key> is calling action written in selectionListner...

Answer (score 0):

After trying lots of work arounds, I'm finally able to assign shortcut key to SWT button with image.

SWT Button.class make use of getText() method to find mnemonic, so overring getText() method of Button.class and returing mnemonic key will serve the purpose. checkSubclass() method should also be overridden to do nothing otherwise swt's *Subclassing not allowed* error will occure.

```
Button newButton = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH){
        @Override
        public String getText() {
            return "&N";
        }

        @Override
        protected void checkSubclass() {
            // Do Nothing to avoid Subclassing Not Allowed error.
        }
    };
    newButton.setImage(newButtonImage);
```

I above example newButton has the shortcut key Alt+N.

Comment: Extremely hacky and clever. Not sure I would recommend this approach though because of the way it skirts the APIs!